# Python. Merge unsorted Arrays (incomplete)

Tags: python, arrays, dictionary, merge

I have three arrays:

```
ID, Name, F1,
1, John, 21
5, Peter, 29
4, Don, 50

ID, F2
1, 40
5, 22

Name, F3
Don, 30
Peter, 66
```

And I want to combine them into a single array:

```
ID, Name, F1, F2, F3
1, John, 21, 40, NaN
5, Peter, 29, 22, 66
4, Don, 50, NaN, 50
```

How can I do this in Python?
I tried using dictionaries but wasnt succesful.

Code:

```
A = np.array([[1, "John", 21], [5, "Peter", 29],[4, "Don", 50]])
B = np.array([[1, 40],[5, 22]])
C = np.array([["Don", 30],["Peter", 66]])
```

creating a dictionary:

```
ID = A[:,0]
Name = A[:,1]
zipbObj = zip(ID, Name)
dictIDName = dict(zipbObj)
```

But now I dont know how to look through the arrays B,C in a general way.

Comment: Can you provide the actual code where you've tried to solve the problem? Please include the original data-structure of the arrays, so that we can initialize them when trying to help you.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`pandas.merge_ordered`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge_ordered.html#pandas.merge_ordered):

```
pd.merge_ordered(pd.merge_ordered(df1, df2), df3)
```

Per example

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'ID': [1,5,4],
                    'Name': ['John', 'Peter', 'Don'],
                    'F1': [21, 29, 50]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'ID': [1,5],
                    'F2': [40, 22]})
df3 = pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['Don', 'Peter'],
                    'F3': [30,66]})

print(pd.merge_ordered(pd.merge_ordered(df1, df2), df3))
```

Result:

```
   ID   Name  F1    F2    F3
0   4    Don  50   NaN  30.0
1   1   John  21  40.0   NaN
2   5  Peter  29  22.0  66.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Sets can be used to carry out mathematical set operations like union, intersection, difference and symmetric difference. Maybe this tutorial will be helpful https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/set

Answer (score 0):

I have prepared a little function that can do this:

```
#ID,Name,F1
arr1=[[1,'Jhon',21],[5,'Peter',29],[4,'Don',29]]
#ID,F2
arr2=[[1,40],[5,22]]
#Name,F3    
arr3=[['Don',30],['Peter',66]]

def merge_arrs(a1,a2,a3):
    res=[]
    dim=len(arr1)
    for i in range(0,dim):
        res.append([a1[i][0],a1[i][1],a1[i][2],None,None])

    for i in range(0,len(a2)):
        idx=-1
        for j in range(0,dim):
            try:
                a1[j].index(a2[i][0])
                idx=j
                break
            except ValueError as ve:
                continue
            if(idx>=0):
                res[idx][3]=a2[i][1]

    for i in range(0,len(a3)):
        idx=-1
        for j in range(0,dim):
            try:
                a1[j].index(a3[i][0])
                idx=j
                break
            except ValueError as ve:
                continue
            if(idx>=0):
                res[idx][4]=a2[i][1]


    return res

print(merge_arrs(arr1,arr2,arr3))
```

the result is: `[[1, 'Jhon', 21, 40, None], [5, 'Peter', 29, 22, 22], [4, 'Don', 29, None, 40]]`

I hope this can helps. Good luck!